# Add 2 days work for Date vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, date

Please I need Help , I want to get the days between 2 dates not including Friday if the first date count 2 days of it except Friday do something 
for example : date1 = 17/10/2016 date2 = date.now 
I want to add 2 days to date1 and check if date1 < date2 then do something

more enplane : if have application to add invoices each invoice added have date 
and code check every day and get the date of today , every day check if invoice date have 2 days except the Friday not calculated do something .

I think about it to get the day of Date1.day + 2 and compare it with date.day of today

```
GetDayOfDate = Date1.day + 2
TodayDate = Date.Now.Day 
if GetDayOfDate < TodayDate  then
do somthing
End If
```

But this code is not complete becouse i did not want to calculate the Friday and also if the day of today is in the first of the next month then the condition will not apply because the day of today is < GetDayOfDate

Any Idea how to code this ?!

Hope you got what i mean :D

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek

Comment: Clue: `YourDate.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Friday`

Answer (score 0):

Guys I found the soulution and test it here you are if any one need it

```
Dim GetDate As Date
GetDate = 'put the date you want to increment it 2 business days
Dim numDays As Integer
numDays = 2
Dim totalDays As Integer
Dim businessDays As Integer
Dim currDate As DateTime
totalDays = 0
businessDays = 0
   While businessDays < numDays
      totalDays += 1
      currDate = GetDate.AddDays(totalDays)
      If Not (currDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday) Then
         businessDays += 1
      End If
   End While
   'to check if the date after increment the 2 work days are less than the day of now 
   If currDate < Date.Now Then
     'date is expired
   else
     'date is not expired yet
   End If
```